# ionic 3 check if value exist in an array in ngfor loop

Tags: ionic3, ngfor, angular-ng-if

i have an ngFor loop that shows all interests. Next I have an ngIf statemnt that checks if the user has already added the interests as his interest from the user_interests page. I have 2 methods I have tried but cant seem to get it right.
Method 1 
First I  loaded all the interests and passed the interest id to a function myInterests which returned true/false if the user has that interest added to their interests or not Next in in the template file i did this

```
<div class="interest card" *ngFor="let interest of interests"  margin-bottom>
  <!--slides-->
  <ion-slides class="to-top" pager>
    <ion-slide>
      <img [src]="interest.interest_img" alt="" class="img">
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
  <p class="secondary"> {{interest.interest_detail}}</p>
    <div class="oba" *ngIf="myInterests(interest.interest_id) =='false'; else showRemove"> 
    <button ion-button icon-start block color="dark" tappable  (click)="addInterest(interest.id)">  
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon> Follow </button> 
    </div>
    <ng-template #showRemove> 
        <div color="dark" class="button" tappable (click)="removeInterest(interest.id)" > 
        <ion-icon name="minus">UnFollow </ion-icon> 
    </div>  
    </ng-template> 

</div>
```

myInterests(iid) is a function that returns true or false from the api. 
Problem is this loops forever showing the loader.

 
Method 2 
I simply loaded all interests and user interests as arrays allInterests and myInterests. Next in in the template file i can not yet figure out how to check if the users interest is equal to the interest in the array 
say something like `<div *ngIf="interest.interest_id in array myinterests.interest_id; else showRemove">` 

 
 Below is the functions 
 
`allInterests() {
     let loader = this.loading.create({

```
content: 'Processing please wait…',

});
   loader.present();
    this.apiProvider.allInterests()
    .then(data => {
      this.interets = data;
      console.log('all returns: ', data);
    });  
    loader.dismiss(); 
}

myInterests(iid) {
 let loader = this.loading.create({

content: 'Processing please wait…',

});
   loader.present();
    this.storage.get('userInfo').then((uInfo)=>{
             if (uInfo.id != null) {
     let userid = uInfo.id;
    this.apiProvider.checkInterests(userid, iid)
    .then(data => {
      this.myinterests = data;
      console.log('my return: ', data);
      return data;
    });

  } 
     });   
    loader.dismiss(); 
}` <br>
```

the console is able to display all returns but hangs there. which means (i guess) it doesnt get to the myInterests() function. But if I remove the function from the if condition at least the interests display

Comment: Have you checked that whether myInterests() function gets input and from the ngFor and returns any value ? I mean there are 2 possibility which one of them is myInterests() function does not work well or cannot be reached and second one is with ngIf.

Comment: exactly what I thought @ShahriyarMammadli i have edited to include the functions.

Comment: As I mentioned in answer, if your function do work, then provided html should also work. I tested it. Respond if you still have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that your `myInterests(id)` function works well and returns true if interest is added by user.

```
<div class="interest card" *ngFor="let interest of interests"  margin-bottom>
  <!--slides-->
  <ion-slides class="to-top" pager>
    <ion-slide>
      <img [src]="interest.interest_img" alt="" class="img">
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
  <p class="secondary"> {{interest.interest_detail}}</p>
    <div class="oba" *ngIf="!myInterests(interest.interest_id)"> 
    <button ion-button icon-start block color="dark" tappable  (click)="addInterest(interest.id)">  
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon> Follow </button> 
    </div>
    <ng-template *ngIf="myInterests(interest.interest_id)"> 
        <div color="dark" class="button" tappable (click)="removeInterest(interest.id)" > 
        <ion-icon name="minus">UnFollow </ion-icon> 
    </div>  
    </ng-template> 

</div>
```

This should work as you desire.